# overlay 'new' banner over Ionicon icon

Tags: html, css, favicon, ionicons

I'm using Ionicons (http://ionicons.com/) and I'm new to css. I'm wondering whether it's possible to overlay a banner that states 'new' over the top right corner of the Icon.

Is there an easy/standard way of doing this? (either to a ionicon or a favicon)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following **new** class to any icon that you want:

```
.new:after {
      content: 'new';
      position: relative;
      top: -10px;
      left: -2px;
      background-color: tomato;
      font-size: xx-small;
 }
```

You can change the color and position and add any other style as you wish.

```css
.new:after {
  content: 'new';
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: xx-small;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="ion-ios-flask new"></i>
```

Comment: This should be the answer. The values may differ based on your style though.